# angular cli errors after updating to @angular/cli 1.0.0 rc1

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am getting below errors similar to below after updating to most recent version of angular cli

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 19:46 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol CUSTOM_ERROR_PROVIDER in
>   /src/app/custom-error-handler.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in 
>   src/app/app.module.ts

Below is my custom error provider

> export var CUSTOM_ERROR_PROVIDER = [{
>             provide: ErrorHandler, useFactory: (appInsightsService: AppInsightsService) =>
>             new CustomErrorHandler(appInsightsService), deps: [AppInsightsService]
>       }];

I understand these are errors because of aot compilation. When I try to run project locally using "ng serve" command I am not using --aot switch. How can I fix these errors if I am not concerned about aot compilation? Also, what is better way of writing code if I want to make my code aot compatible ?

**Update**

After changing CUSTOM_ERROR_PROVIDER to a pure function, I am getting another error.

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Expression form not supported (position 8:5 in the original .ts file),
>   resolving symbol homeRoutes in /app/main/home/home.routing.ts,
>   resolving symbol MainRoutingModule in   src/app/main/main.routing.ts,
>   resolving symbol MainRoutingModule in  src/app/main/main.routing.ts,
>   resolving symbol MainRoutingModule in
>   mbe50web/src/app/main/main.routing.ts

Below is the home routes constant it is complaining about

> export const homeRoutes: Routes = [
>       {
>           path: 'home', 
>           component: HomeComponent,
>       } as Route,
>     ];

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Comment: @yurzui I am not using --aot while using angular cli though.

Comment: Did you try that solution? See also https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3368

Comment: @yurzui yes, I have tried that and fixed few errors. Unfortunately, we have to fix many more functions to use aot. I was wondering if we can use latest version of angular cli and gradually update the code to be aot compatible.